# Child component not loading in angular

Tags: angular, components

I have a child component in the angular. This child component consists of the pagination logic. What I want is that when the list gets retrieved and displayed on the screen, the child component will then be shown, But it is not shown sometimes when I go on refreshing the browser.

Child component:

```
  <div class="page-paginator">
    <app-paginator
      *ngIf="batchesList"
      class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap"
      [paginator]="paginator"
      [totalItems]="totalItems"
      [isLoading]="isLoading"
      (paginate)="paginate($event)"
    ></app-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to put the getList() funnction in both the constructor and onInit but with no success:

```
this.getList();



  getList() {
        this.commonService.API_URL = `${environment.apiUrl}/admin/employees?limit=${this.commonService.paginator.pageSize}&offset=${(this.commonService.paginator.pageSize) * (this.commonService.paginator.page - 1)} & searchInput=`;
        this.commonService.fetch();
      }
```

Comment: Post getList() code, I am assuming that you are passing batches list as an input property to child component.

Comment: Yes, I am passing as the input property.

Comment: getList() {
    this.commonService.API_URL = `${environment.apiUrl}/admin/employees?limit=${this.commonService.paginator.pageSize}&offset=${(this.commonService.paginator.pageSize) * (this.commonService.paginator.page - 1)}&searchInput=`;
    this.commonService.fetch();
  }